# Forward playback using spacebar just go one step/frame

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In video editing mode, I added my own video that I shot from my mobile. I pressed the forward button and it went just one step/frame forward only. When I pressed the backward playback button, it played the whole video backward.

How can I make the forward playback button to play the whole video rather than just one step forward? Is there any setting I should look into for this?

Thank you.
Tom.

Comment: This should work. Maybe a screenshot can clarify something?

Comment: maybe you just misplaced your video strip or your playhead? Anyway, it would be easier to figure out with a screenshoot or a blender file.

Comment: I remember someone else asking the same question, but I don’t remember the answer. Hang on…

Comment: In Preferences > System > Audio Device try change it to something else(ex. do not use Pulseaudio).

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `Timeline` Playback Sync option is set to “Play Every Frame.” Details are in [this related answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234658/90622).