# Image Sequence won't play

Tags: materials, import, image, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to import an image sequence with an alpha transparent background using "images as planes". However the video wont play when I move the playhead in the timeline. It just shows the first frame of the animation. ideas are much appreciated!

-I already checked the sequence itself. the images should be fine.
-here is a screenshot of the import settings

[image]

Comment: hello, we can't see any screenshot

Comment: @Emir's comment should solve it. Also there is a checkbox titled 'animate image sequences' when you import your images.

Comment: @moonboots the screenshot is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

In your `Timeline` `Playback` `Sync` popover menu, is the  active option other than “Play Every Frame”? “Sync to Audio“ is a default that messes with image sequence playback.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html#header

[image: Timeline editor Playback options]